# Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I am getting this error "Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name."
I have a struct called spectData and it looks like this

```
spectData{1} = 

data: [256x26 double]
textdata: {1x26 cell}
colheaders: {1x26 cell}
Row: [256x1 double]
Col: [256x1 double]
Cho: [256x1 double]
Cho0x25SD: [256x1 double]
Cho0x2FCit: [256x1 double]
PCho: [256x1 double]
PCho0x25SD: [256x1 double]
```

I try and assign this in a function call the line of code looks like this. This is the line of code that matlab says the error is at.

```
 SDdata = spectData{sliceNum - firstSlice}.(MetabMapSDString);
```

where metabString is a string of one of the names for example 'PCho0x25SD' spectData has 4 sub structs in total all like this one I displayed. What am I doing wrong?? It is a double so it should be ok I thought.

Comment: Does `MetabMapSDString` always contain valid fieldnames? Did you check for typos?

Comment: From what I cab tell after checking there are no typos. For some reason now the error is not happening.

Comment: The error seems to be inconsistent. I cant seem to make it happen again and I didnt change anything.

Comment: Congratulations then. Will keep my fingers crossed that the error does not happen again.

Comment: Add a try/catch block, and everytime the error happens examine MetabMapSDString AND the field of the struct.  Also, since you are storing the struct in a CELL ARRAY, the fields might not be consistent in the particular struct you are indexing into.  Only an array of structs is guaranteed to have a consistent structure.

Comment: Deleted comment and put it into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matlab can give this sometimes misleading error message when you accidentally pass a cell array instead of a string.  The following example gives the same error:

```
fields = {'foo', 'bar'}
s = struct('foo', 23, 'bar', pi)

for f = fields
  disp(f)
  s.(f) = 0
end
```

If this is your problem (test the actual type of your field name with e.g. `whos`), it should help to say `f = char(f)`.

Comment: `f=f{:}` or `f=f{1}` also works, not sure if there is any particular advantage to either way. +1

Comment: @zelanix The advantage of `char` is that you can do `char(f(1))`, but not `f(1){1}`

Answer (score 2):

A string is represented in matlab as cell. while literal strings are of type char array.
They prints differently. A cell string prints as

```
ans =

    'abc'
```

while a regular char array prints as

```
ans = 
abc
```

Now comes to the difference of the two builtin functions: `cellstr` converts char array to string while `char` converts a cell string to char array.

So in your case, you should use `char(MetabMapSDString)` as your dynamic struct reference.